# Why is the determinant useful when finding eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I understand that the eigenvectors of a linear transformation are the vectors that, when transformed, are simply scaled by a factor of the corresponding eigenvalue. Therefore
$$
A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}.
$$
We can replace the scaling of the vector $\vec{x}$ by $\lambda$ with its equivalent linear transformation, $\lambda I$. Then we can rearrange this equation as follows:
$$
A\vec{x}-(\lambda I)\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\ 
(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\ 
$$
For this to be true either $\vec{x}$ must be a zero vector or the transformation $A-\lambda I$ must have $\vec{x}$ in its null-space. The course I'm following says that we can solve for $\lambda$ by finding when the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is zero, but why does that guarantee that $\vec{x}$ will become the zero vector when transformed by $A-\lambda I$? I understand that for $\vec{x}$ to be an eigenvector this transformation *must* have a determinant of zero, but I don't see how the inverse can be true; having a determinant of zero doesn't gaurantee that $\vec{x}$ will be transformed into the zero vector. For example, let
$$
(A-\lambda I) = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, although
$\det\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = 0$, it does not gaurantee $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}$ to be the zero vector.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix} 
$$
We can see that the transformation gives us $\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and not the zero vector. Why does finding when the determinant of this transformation is equal to zero help us find the eigenvectors? Am I missing something?

Comment: If $\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$ then *there exists* a nonzero vector $x$ such that $(A - \lambda I)x =0$.

Comment: Since $\det\pmatrix{1&2\\0&0}=0$, there is a non-zero vector $\vec x$ such that $\pmatrix{1&2\\0&0}\vec x=\pmatrix{0\\0}$, namely, $\pmatrix{2\\-1}$

Comment: So because all vectors are squished onto the x-axis, there must be some vector $\vec{x}$ that maps onto the zero vector?

Comment: It's not clear to me where $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ comes from. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @WillOrrick I just made up an example to explain my confusion around the statement $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=0$. More specifically, I am confused as to why it is helpful to solve for when the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is zero, as even though the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is zero, it doesn't guarantee that a vector $\vec{x}$ (in this case $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$) will be mapped onto the zero vector.

Comment: @WillOrrick I've edited my question-- hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Since you have a good grasp on what is happening conceptually with transformations, you are perfectly suited to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g). I believe it answers your question, even though a great deal of it may be review.

Comment: "The course I'm following says that we can solve for $\lambda$ by finding when the determinant of $A - \lambda I$ is zero." This should be stated more carefully. To say that a number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ means that *there exists* a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$. Equivalently, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$. You can find the eigenvalues of $A$ by solving that equation for $\lambda$. Once you find an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you do not yet know a vector $x$ for which $Ax = \lambda x$. You still have to find $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ guarantees that there exists a nonzero $\vec{x}$ such that $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=0$. It does not mean that any $\vec{x}$ will work, and your $\vec{x}$, with your $A-\lambda I$, does not work. There is an $\vec{x}$ that does, however, namely
$$
\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Any scalar multiple of this vector will also work.

The usual situation is a bit different from yours. Usually you have $A$, but $\lambda$ is not known. So $\det(A-\lambda I)$ will be an expression involving $\lambda$. In fact, it will be a polynomial in $\lambda$ whose degree is the dimension of $A$. The roots of this polynomial are the eigenvalues, and each one determines a space of eigenvectors. If I'm understanding correctly, you must already know $\lambda$ since your matrix $A-\lambda I$ is a constant matrix.

There seems to be some confusion at the end of your post where you were expecting $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}$ to lie in the span of $\vec{x}$. In fact, you should be expecting $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}$ to be the zero vector.

Perhaps you meant that $A\vec{x}$ should be in the span of $\vec{x}$? If so, that would be correct, but you haven't told us what $A$ is—you've only told us what $A-\lambda I$ is.

**Added:** Here's a complete example. We will compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We want to find pairs $(\lambda,\vec{x})$ such that $A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$, or $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$.

Now
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & 2\\ 3 & -\lambda\end{bmatrix}=\lambda^2-\lambda-6,
$$
which has roots $\lambda=-2,\ 3$. If $\lambda=-2$, then
$$
(A-\lambda I)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
and so we have found an eigenvector. Indeed
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\ 6\end{bmatrix}=-2\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -3\end{bmatrix}.
$$

If you try out the other eigenvalue, $\lambda=3$, you should find that $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector.

**Second addition:** There seems to be a fundamental misconception here. Except in rare cases, not every vector is an eigenvector. So we can't (and don't) require that $A-\lambda I$ map every $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{0}$.

On the other hand $A-\lambda I$ **always** maps $\vec{0}$ to $\vec{0}$, no matter what $\lambda$ is. That's not what we're interested in either. We don't consider the zero vector to be an eigenvector.

To seek an eigenvector means to seek a **particular non-zero** $\vec{x}$ such that $A-\lambda I$ maps $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{0}$. If $\det(A-\lambda I)\ne0$ then there is no such non-zero $\vec{x}$. But if $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, then there does exist such a non-zero $\vec{x}$, although we still have to figure out what $\vec{x}$ is by solving the linear system $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$.

So in your example, $\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=0$ guarantees that there is a non-zero $\vec{x}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}=\vec{0}$, but $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is not such an $\vec{x}$.

Let's find such an $\vec{x}$ by writing $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and solving for $x$ and $y$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The second row of this matrix equation holds true no matter what $x$ and $y$ are, so the only condition is that provided by the first row, $1x+2y=0$. This gives $x=-2y$, so any vector of the form
$$
\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}-2y\\ y\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an eigenvector, as long as $y$ is not zero. (If $y$ is zero, we get the zero vector, which we already knew about and aren't interested in.)

What goes wrong if $\det(A-\lambda I)\ne0$? In that case $A-\lambda I$ is an invertible matrix. So
$$
(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}
$$
has the same solution set as
$$
(A-\lambda I)^{-1}(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\vec{0},
$$
which reduces to $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$,
the solution we aren't interested in.

Comment: Yes I meant to say that $A\vec{x}$ should be in the span of $\vec{x}$.

Comment: I think you may need to edit your post and let us know what $A$ is. Or is the matrix in your problem $A$? If so, then you need to be computing the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & 2\\ 0 & -\lambda\end{bmatrix}$. Then solve for $\lambda=0$.

Comment: There's no problem I'm trying to solve, I'm just struggling to understand eigenvectors conceptually. The example I gave was just to demonstrate my confusion about the statement $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x} = 0$

Comment: Your second addition was very helpful, thanks!